# Change cell font color in Kable using kableextra, in pdf rmarkdown xelatex

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

do you know if there is anyway to change the font color of a kable table cell.

it is very important for me to do it with kable or kableextra because I need a stripped table, with some bold columns or rows, but I also need some cells to be in another color. This is the code I would like to extend not to modify if possible

```
library(kableExtra)

x_latex <- knitr::kable(head(mtcars), "latex", booktabs=T, col.names = NULL)
#kable_styling(x_latex, latex_options = "striped", position = "float_left")
kable_styling(x_latex, latex_options = c("striped","HOLD_position"), stripe_color = "gray!13") %>%
sub("\\\\toprule", "", .) %>%
sub("\\\\bottomrule", "", .)  %>% row_spec(2,bold=TRUE)
```

now lets say rows 1, 1 and 2, 2 need to be red, how could I achieve this? Can I use cell_spec?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @JK Lambert. Did you check the [documentation](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf)?

Comment: I did, and nothing is shown there, I was thinking maybe someone had worked out a workaround, do you have any ideas?